# Change variable inside listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, seekbar

I am attempting to set a variable x, which is contained by my class fragment. The class fragment contains a seekArc, and that seekArc's onSeekArcChangeListener. I am attempting to change variable x, which cannot be final, from inside the onProgressChanged method within the onSeekArcChangeListener. When I attempt to x.setVar() I get an error that x == null. Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

```
private Y y = new Y();

...    

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Initializing Objects/Widgets
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display, container, false);

        seekArcOuter = (SeekArc) v.findViewById(R.id.seekArcOuter);


        //error is occuring online inside of the change listener method
        seekArcOuter.setOnSeekArcChangeListener(new SeekArc.OnSeekArcChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekArc seekArc) {
                //TODO
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekArc seekArc) {
                //TODO 
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekArc seekArc, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                if(y!=null)
                    y.setX(seekArc.getProgress());
                else
                    Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged: y==null");
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

ERROR:

```
D////Display_Frag///: setY: onProgressChanged: y==null
```

Comment: If you could show snippets of code and the error log that would be very helpful

Comment: Please, paste some code

Comment: Code or it didn't happen :D

Comment: Can you make variable x a member variable of the class

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the Y class?